# Android NDK C print log on android studio 2.2?

Tags: android, android-ndk, ndk-build

Developing ndk programing. How to solve it error. Please give me

**Error**

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:linkAppArm64-v8aDebugSharedLibrary'.
>   A build operation failed.
>   Linker failed while linking libApp.so.
>   See the complete log at: file:///C:/android/NDKTutorialTwo/app/build/tmp/linkAppArm64-v8aDebugSharedLibrary/output.txt

**Output.txt**

> See file:///C:/android/NDKTutorialTwo/app/build/tmp/linkAppArm64-v8aDebugSharedLibrary/output.txt for all output for linkAppArm64-v8aDebugSharedLibrary.
>   linking libApp.so failed.
>   C:/androidNDK/android-ndk-r12b/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmui
>   collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>
> Finished linkAppArm64-v8aDebugSharedLibrary, see full log file:///C:/android/NDKTutorialTwo/app/build/tmp/linkAppArm64-v8aDebugSharedLibrary/output.txt.

**App level Gradle**
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

```
model{
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 24
            buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
            defaultConfig {
                applicationId "com.metroinfrasys.ndktutorialtwo"
                minSdkVersion.apiLevel 16
                targetSdkVersion.apiLevel 24
                versionCode 1
                versionName "1.0"
                testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
            }
            buildTypes {
                release {
                    minifyEnabled false
                    proguardFiles.add(file('proguard-android.txt'))
                }
            }

            ndk {
                moduleName "App"
                ldLibs.add("EGL")
                ldLibs.add("android")
                ldLibs.add("GLESv2")
                ldLibs.add("dl")
                ldLibs.add("log")
                ldLibs.add("mui")
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    }
```

**Please give any solution**

Comment: What is `ldLibs.add("mui")` for? There is no system library with such name. Is it your own or third-party one?

Comment: I want to add this   ldLibs.add("log") but not trace my logCat in native